# Obtener el valor de un DropDownList con Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework, razor

Buen dia tengo el siguiente problema tengo un DropDownList que corresponde a una foreign key el cual lleno desde mi controlador de la siguiente manera

```
ViewBag.Eq_tblFabricante_id = new SelectList(db.Eq_tblFabricante, "id", "Fabricante");
```

y llega asi a mi Vista

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Eq_tblFabricante_id, "Fabricante", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div>
        @Html.DropDownList("Eq_tblFabricante_id", null, htmlAttributes: new { @id = "Fabricante", @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Eq_tblFabricante_id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Desde mi Jquery quiero pedirle que si detecta que el valor del DropDownList sea igual a "Microsoft" me oculte el elemento div con el Id asignado

Actualmente lo hace pero no detecta la palabra "Microsoft" si no su Id en la base de datos, así lo estoy manejando momentáneamente pero quisiera que me detectara el cambio sobre el valor "Microsoft" no sobre su Id

esta es mi funcion

```
$(function () {

$("#Fabricante").on('change', function () {
   
    var selectValue = $(this).val();
  
    if (selectValue == "3") {
        $("#tel").show();
    } else {
        $("#tel").hide();
    }

}).change(); });
```

Comment: Prueba con .text(); en lugar de .val()

Comment: Que tal edgar, eh probado con la modificación que me dijiste pero me trae ambos elementos de la lista  en este caso solo tengo dos al momento de imprimir un alert para ver que dato toma alert($(this).text()); me manda que lo que entra es el texto de la lista mas no el valor

Comment: pero entendi que el texto necesitabas no es asi?

Comment: el dropdawnlist cuando lo lleno con desde el controlador manda (llave, valor) actualmente de a manera en que lo tengo la decisión de ocultar el elemento identificado #tel la toma a partir de que si selectValue es igual a 3 en este caso mi lista esta así  (1-cisco),(2,IBM),(3,Microsoft), aquí esta tomando la decisión a partir de que detecta en la lista el elemento 3 pero yo quiero que en vez de evaluar el id me haga la evaluación por el texto, con la modificación que sugeriste al imprimir  $(this).text(); me aparece que se trae todo el listado entonces no puede hacer la comparación

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolví de la siguiente manera

```
$(function () {
    $("#Fabricante").on('change', function () {
        var selectValue = $("#Fabricante option:selected").text();
        if (selectValue == "MICROSOFT" ) {
            $("#tel").show();
        } else {
            $("#tel").hide();
        }
    }).change();
});
```

Cambie el `var selectValue = $(this).val();` por  `var selectValue = $("#Fabricante option:selected").text();`

espero esto le llegue a servir a alguien que se encuentre con el mismo problema que yo y si es así califiquen mi pregunta como útil